# Ascending and Descending in Ionic

Tags: php, ionic-framework

I have a problem in ionic.

so, when i choose the select list in "A-Z", it means ascending.

[image]

and when i click the button, it should go to another state that show my list.

[image]

if A-Z is choosen, the "goal futsal " should be number 1 right?. 
how can i do that? what's wrong with my code. Please help.
thank you.

here is controller that i use in my code.

```
.controller('cariCtrl',function($scope,$http,$state,Cari){
   $scope.cari = function(input){
   Cari.setDaerah(input.daerah);
   Cari.setNama(input.nama);
   Cari.setUrut(input.urut);
   $state.go('back.list');
  }
})
  .controller('listCtrl',function($scope,$http,$state,$ionicHistory,Cari){
  $scope.user = [];
  $scope.lapangan = [];

  $scope.goBack = function(){
      $state.go('menu.cari', {}, {
          reload: true
      });
  }
  $http({
      method: 'POST',
      data:{
          daerah: Cari.getDaerah(),
          nama: Cari.getNama(),
          urut: Cari.getUrut()
      },
      url: "http://localhost/TA2/admin/app/getSearchLapangan.php"
  }).success(function(data){
      $scope.lapangan = data;
  }).error(function(data, status,headers,config) {
      alert(status);
      alert(headers);
  }); 
})
```

in app.js, i add this :

```
.factory('Cari', function(){
   var data = {
   daerah: '',
   nama: '',
   urut: ''
 };
 return {
    getDaerah: function(){
    return data.daerah;
   },
    setDaerah: function(pdaerah){
    data.daerah = pdaerah;
   },
    getNama: function(){
    return data.nama;
   },
    setNama: function(pnama){
    data.nama = pnama;
   },
    getUrut: function(){
    return data.nama;
   },
     setUrut: function(purut){
     data.urut = purut;
    }
   };
 })
```

The sql query is like this:

```
$daerah = $objData->daerah;
$nama = $objData->nama;
$urut = $objData->urut;
$SQL = "";
if ($urut == 0) {
   $SQL = "SELECT L.*, (SELECT path FROM gambar G WHERE G.id_lapangan = L.id_lapangan LIMIT 1) as path from lapangan L WHERE daerah LIKE '" . $daerah . "%' AND nama LIKE '" . $nama . "%' ORDER BY nama ASC;";
} else {
   $SQL = "SELECT L.*, (SELECT path FROM gambar G WHERE G.id_lapangan = L.id_lapangan LIMIT 1) as path from lapangan L WHERE daerah LIKE '" . $daerah . "%' AND nama LIKE '" . $nama . "%' ORDER BY nama DESC;";
}

$result = mysql_query($SQL, $link);
$array = array();
$counter = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $array[$counter] = $row;
  $counter++;
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

Here is my view :

```
<label class="item item-select">
<select style="right: auto;" ng-model="input.urut">
   <option value="">Silahkan Pilih Urutan</option>
   <option value="0">A-Z</option>
   <option value="1">Z-A</option>
</select>
</label>
<button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="cari(input)">Cari</button>
```

by the way, i use php. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can set **[Ascending](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)**  and **[Descending](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)**  order list in **Ionic**

```
<label class="item item-select">
     <select ng-model="input.urut" ng-change="onChange(input.urut)">
       <option value="">Silahkan Pilih Urutan</option>
       <option value="0">A-Z</option>
       <option value="1">Z-A</option>
     </select>
</label>
<div class="list">
    <a ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy : 'album' : flag" href="#" class="item item-thumbnail-left">
        <h2>{{ item.album }}</h2>
        <h4>{{ item.artist }}</h4>
    </a>
</div>
```

and add in your controller

```
$scope.flag = false;
$scope.onChange = function(urut){
    if(urut == 0){
       $scope.flag = false;
    }else{
        $scope.flag = true;
     }
}
```

**[Updated Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/JH3cmCfOUieuKMbTt0pG?p=preview)**

Comment: hi bro ved. i'm sorry but it didn't work. what is flag? where controller should i put the code? i've put that code cariCtrl or listCtrl. but it didn't work.

Comment: ohh..i see. in your case, it is change on the same state. what about different state?

Comment: as you see, i have 2 controller, because i have 2 state. state one is cariCtrl which contain select option "A-Z" and a button. when i click the button, the result of the list is on state 2 which have "listCtrl". 
i have put onChange code in my button function. but it still didn't work.

Comment: now see my plnkr example , I have updated. http://plnkr.co/edit/JH3cmCfOUieuKMbTt0pG?p=preview

Comment: i think your code is right. but, i don't know. it still didn't work. i'll try it for more. by the way, thanks man. you are a life saver!